# Writing a file client side using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, xlsx

Can we write an xlsx file on client side using angular js .If it is possible then please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export data from AngularJS to XLS, XLSX and CSV formats with [Alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql) library.

For example we want to write a data which we saved in test variable in an XLSX file through click a button. To do this just use following steps:

1- Include following files in your page:

```
 <script src="http://alasql.org/console/alasql.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="http://alasql.org/console/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
```

2- So Then make a function in controller to save the test variable as a xlsx file:

```
$scope.test = [{a:2,b:8,c:9},{a:0,b:14,c:12},{a:24,b:35,c:76}];
$scope.saveAsXlsx = function () {
   alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("output.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?',[$scope.test]);
}
```

So We save the data which we had in variable test into a file which we named it output.xlsx here.

3- The last part is the easiest part. Run the function on click on a button:

```
 <button ng-click="saveAsXlsx()" >Save as XLSX</button>
```

Above solution is a js library which can be used with jQuery, js  and angularJS. If you are looking for something just made for angular then in addition of this solution, you can use ng-csv library. If you want to just have a spreadsheet you can use [ng-csv](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-csv) library too. It is very easy but you can't get XLSX, you will get the spreadsheet file with CSV format.

Comment: Hi Iman sedighi, can you answer this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369082/excel-download-is-not-working-in-mean-stack-app/44373532#44373532

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like [angular-xlsx](https://libraries.io/bower/angular-xlsx) or [js-xlsx](https://libraries.io/bower/js-xlsx) to help you with this process.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your excel file.

install `npm install excel4node`

and then use the basic code

```
// Require library 
var xl = require('excel4node');

// Create a new instance of a Workbook class 
var wb = new xl.Workbook();

// Add Worksheets to the workbook 
var ws = wb.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');
var ws2 = wb.addWorksheet('Sheet 2');

// Create a reusable style 
var style = wb.createStyle({
    font: {
        color: '#FF0800',
        size: 12
    },
    numberFormat: '$#,##0.00; ($#,##0.00); -'
});

// Set value of cell A1 to 100 as a number type styled with paramaters of style 
ws.cell(1,1).number(100).style(style);

// Set value of cell B1 to 300 as a number type styled with paramaters of style 
ws.cell(1,2).number(200).style(style);

// Set value of cell C1 to a formula styled with paramaters of style 
ws.cell(1,3).formula('A1 + B1').style(style);

// Set value of cell A2 to 'string' styled with paramaters of style 
ws.cell(2,1).string('string').style(style);

// Set value of cell A3 to true as a boolean type styled with paramaters of style but with an adjustment to the font size. 
ws.cell(3,1).bool(true).style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});

wb.write('Excel.xlsx');
```

here i have added ref link :https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node