# Excel download is not working in MEAN stack app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I want to download the excel file when i click the button.

When i click the download button, I want to create a Excel file with dynamic data from data base and download it (Note: Don't want to create and store the excel file into physical path and then download it).

> Html Code

```
<button ng-click="exportData()" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-create">Download</button>
```

> Controller Code

```
 $scope.exportData = function () {
     $http.get('/Getexcel').then(function (response) {
     });
 };
```

> Server code

```
 const ExcelConfig = require('./public/Models/Schema/excel');
    app.get('/Getexcel', ExcelConfig.getexceldata);
```

> note :
>   ExcelConfig contain path of schema code
>
> excel.js code

```
// Require library 
var xl = require('excel4node');
const tempfile = require('tempfile');

// Create a new instance of a Workbook class 
var wb = new xl.Workbook();

// Add Worksheets to the workbook 
var ws = wb.addWorksheet('MaterialFlowSheet');
// Create a reusable style 
var style = wb.createStyle({
    font: {
        color: '#FF0800',
        size: 12
    },
    numberFormat: '$#,##0.00; ($#,##0.00); -'
});

exports.getexceldata = (req, res) => {
    ws.cell(1, 1).string('BatchId').style(style);
    ws.cell(1, 2).string('Source').style(style);
    ws.column(2).setWidth(50);
    ws.row(1).setHeight(20);
    ws.cell(1, 3).string('Destination').style(style);
    ws.column(3).setWidth(50);
    ws.row(1).setHeight(20);
    ws.cell(1, 4).string('DistanceBetweenTwoBuilding').style(style);
    ws.column(4).setWidth(25);
    ws.row(1).setHeight(20);
    ws.cell(1, 5).string('SKU').style(style);
    ws.cell(1, 6).string('UOM').style(style);
    ws.cell(1, 7).string('QtyToBeDelivered').style(style);
    ws.column(7).setWidth(20);
    ws.row(1).setHeight(20);
    ws.cell(1, 8).string('CartType').style(style);
wb.write('Excel.xlsx');
res.download('\Excel.xlsx');
};
```

I have tried with above sample file download. So when I click the Download button, the file is not downloading instead nothing happened in UI. But I'm Getting downloaded If I access this URL `http://localhost:8080/Getexcel`. 
Can anyone give the solution to download the excel file by clicking the Download button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel file downloading is not working in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112779/excel-file-downloading-is-not-working-in-angular-js)

Comment: Hi David can you find the reason why it is not downloaded the excel file when i click the button

Comment: Can we see an example of the server response? Is it a byte array? If you're returning raw data from the server you probably need to add to the headers call (angular side) `arrayBuffer`.

Comment: `res.download('\Excel.xlsx');` <- did you correct this? single backslash escapes the next character. you should have used double, or even better, a forward slash: `/`

Comment: I believe the mistake lies in handling the download in your client side code...  ajax call will not save the file for you. if you need this solved you can find me on clarity ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You must send response as file

```
app.get('/spreadsheet', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment;filename=data.xls`);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
  res.charset = 'UTF-8';
  res.status(200).end(xls);
});
```

Comment: My assumption is to insert this code in server, rite ? If wrong, where i need to insert it into my application.
and what is the 'xls' from res.status(200).end(xls);, Is it variable or what ?

Comment: An Excel file doesn't have a type of `text/plain`

Comment: `xls` is a content of xls-file. Yeah, `application/vnd.ms-excel` is more revalent than `text/plain`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late but, given that your server-side code is fine (I'm no expert in node or express), you should set the request header in your request:

```
$scope.exportData = function () {
 $http.get('/Getexcel', {responseType: "arraybuffer"}).
....
 };
```

Then maybe use [FileSaver](https://github.com/alferov/angular-file-saver) to save the response to file, like this

```
$scope.exportData = function () {
 $http.get('/Getexcel', {responseType: "arraybuffer"})
    .success(function(response) {
        data     = new Blob([response.data], {type: response.headers('content-type')});

        FileSaver.saveAs(data, filename);
    });
 };
```